# Closed form for $\sum_{i=1}^n 1/\log(i)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, closed-form

[Discounted Cumulative Gain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discounted_cumulative_gain) (in the simpler, binary relevance version) is defined as

$$
DCG_{\text{binary}} := \sum_{i=1}^M \frac{r_i}{\log(i + 1)}
$$
with $r_i\in\{0,1\}$. (Since $2^r-1=r$ for both 0 and 1)

It is commonly normalized with the maximum achievable score called $IDCG$, obtained by sorting the $r_1$ in descending order, which for binary effectively is:
$r_i = \begin{cases}1 & i \leq n\\0 & i > n\end{cases}$. Then
$$
IDCG_{\text{binary}} := \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\log(i + 1)} = \sum_{i=2}^{n+1} \frac{1}{\log(i)}
$$
Rather than computing this with a loop, I am therefore looking for a closed 
form solution of $\sum_{i=2}^n 1/\log(i)$. I could not figure one out myself.

By exponentiation I got this alternate form:
$$
\exp^{IDCG_{\text{binary}}} = \exp^{\sum_{i=2}^{n+1} \frac{1}{\log(i)}}
\\
= \prod_{i=2}^{n+1} \exp\frac{1}{\log(i)}
$$
but that isn't much nicer.

Comment: Your transformation of sum into product is wrong 
$$
\exp(\sum_i 1/\log(i)) = \prod_i \exp(1/\log(i)) \neq \prod_i1/\log(i)
$$

Comment: Thanks. Just ignore that part then. It did not work anyway.

Comment: I'm afraid that the sum $\sum_i 1/\log(i)$ has no closed form. One way to approximate it would be with the integral $\int_2^{n+1} 1/\log(x) dx$ however this integral doesn't a closed form either. It is actually defined to be the logarithm-integral $Li(n+1)$.